# How to log execution time with ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, exception, logging, exceptionhandler

I am trying to refactor my application and now i also want to use an ExceptionHandler.
Therefore I already implemented some Methods like

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<SomeClass> handleException(Exception e) {
// do something
}
```

Now I want to log the execution time of the calling method also when the ExeptionHandler method is called.
In my old code I did it like this:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    
    try {
        // do some fancy code stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logTime(Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis());
    }
}
```

Has anybody an idea of how to get the information of the startTime passed in the ExceptionHandler method? Or is there maybe a much better way to get the information?

I already had a look in the Exception object structure if I could maybe find some of the needed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring AOP to measure execution time and catch exceptions.
[Here](https://medium.com/@mailshine/spring-boot-measure-execution-time-using-spring-aop-and-aspectj-4590d7bd6bb2) is an example. It only measures time. But you can add a try-catch there similar to what you had in your old code.

If you still want to use an `ExceptionHandler`, then you can create `class TimeMeasuredException extends RuntimeException` with `executionTime` field. And then do

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
try {
  point.proceed();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Instant end = Instant.now();
  Duration executionTime = Duration.between(start, end);
  throw new TimeMeasuredException(executionTime, ex);
}
```

Your `ExceptionHandler` should either catch `TimeMeasuredException` or you can catch `Exception` and then check it with `instanceof`.

Comment: Good idea, I think this solution should do it, thanks! :)